# Directly download img tag

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an image tag which is cross-origin, and it's `src` is assigned dynamically.

```
image.src = "http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/" + username + ".png";
```

Obviously this shows up in the document fine but I want the user to be able to save it to their local file system upon the click of a download button. I dynamically create an `a` tag, set the download attribute to the player username (and filetype, png), but I'm not sure what to set the `href` attribute to. Obviously, I could set it to the URL of the actual image tag, but unfortunately, this gives the downloaded file a very ugly and long name, which detracts from user experience. Since the image is cross-origin (and I cannot change this), I can't just plop it onto a canvas and convert it to raw data. But, still, I am sure there is some way to just let the user download from the image element, but I cannot find that way. (As if they right-click and hit "Save image as...")

I have tried setting the `href` attribute of the `a` object directly to the img tag, but the download fails due to "No file".

I have tried setting the `href` attribute to a newly-created `Image` object, but same error.

*Note: Nothing can be done server-side.*
*For testing purposes, the username "ImAlgo" can be used*

Comment: @JaromandaX That note means nothing can be done on my server side.

Comment: re-reading question helped (only had one coffee so far this morning) - I'll remove my comments - but, an example username would help for testing

Comment: I have added a test username

Comment: @JaromandaX The issue is cross-origin. Again, the image is appearing fine in the document. I see it. I'm trying to automatically have it downloaded to a user's computer through JS, but because the image is not on my server, it is being very angry with me.

Comment: @AlgoRythm Is the only issue with using `<a>` element the suggested file name at `Save File` dialog? The user can change the suggested file name at any time before or after downloading file.

Comment: @guest271314 The issue is this is not a dialog, it just saves it directly to the user's download folder as something incredibly difficult to identify - without asking what to call it whatsoever (tested in chrome, default settings)

Comment: @AlgoRythm When tried at chromium the file was offered for download. `var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "ImAlgo";
a.href = "http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/" + username + ".png";
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click()`. The file name can be changed before the file is downloaded.

Comment: @guest271314 You probably have it set to "ask". This is not the default.

Comment: firefox redirects to the image. An alternative approach could be to utilize `YQL`

Comment: And if you set `image.crossOrigin='anonymous'`, are you still unable to get the raw data? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `fetch()`, `YQL` to get `data URI` representation of resource, `<a>` element and `download` attribute to set suggested file name for resource offered for download to user at each chromium and firefox.

```js
let username = "ImAlgo";

let url = `http://skins.minecraft.net/MinecraftSkins/${username}.png`;

let query = `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from data.uri where url="${url}"&format=json&callback=`;

let a = document.createElement("a");

a.download = `${username}.png`;

fetch(query).then(response => response.json())
.then(({query:{results:{url}}}) => {
  a.href = url;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```