# JavaScript: Turning GIF into thumbnail blob or base64 or URL?

Tags: javascript

So, ideally, I would like a user to add a gif to my site and subsequently a thumbnail image for it as well.

Currently, I'm using gifffer() to create a canvas for roughly the first frame of the gif. However, when I try to save this canvas as an image, I get the `tainted` warning. So now I'm trying to figure out the best way to automatically create a thumbnail from a gif?

Thoughts?

Hello, is it me you're searching for?

Comment: How does user "add a gif"? Why is error occurring if user is uploading image?

Comment: I would like users to be able to grab gifs from a URL ideally...

Comment: What do you mean by "grab gifs"?

Comment: For example, the gif url I have been testing with is: `http://bestanimations.com/Animals/Mammals/Cats/catgif/funny-cat-gif-3.gif`

Comment: Ideally, a user can go to my site and save this gif URL in their profile database. This is all good. But, when I want to show them a thumbnail for the gif, I need a thumbnail... preferably a separate image that was created when they first input the URL

Comment: How is error at `canvas` related to Question? Not certain what issue is? Is the resource served with `CORS` headers?

Comment: Well, I get the canvas image fine. But when I try to do something with the canvas like `getDataURL` I get the tainted warning. Now, I know because I'm on localhost, it could be causing an issue, but I was hoping to try a few alternatives before loading onto a server and then testing... but maybe I'm outta luck...

Comment: At which browser are you trying?

Comment: Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Comment: You can launch chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to allow local filesystem access from `file:` protocol, to try process locally; see [JS: how can I base64 encode a local file without XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38887005/js-how-can-i-base64-encode-a-local-file-without-xmlhttprequest/)

Comment: Okay, so I loaded chrome from terminal with this: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files` and then went to localhost and added the gif which produced the canvas. Then I used this jquery to get the data: `$('#showcase_defaultPostID canvas')[0].toDataURL("image/jpg")` and I got this response in the console: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
    at <anonymous>:1:47`

Comment: Did you close all open instances of chrome, or also set a different `--user-data-dir` directory before launching at `terminal`? If chrome is launched from `terminal` while an existing instance is running, chrome will use the open instance settings and configuration directory negating, negating the new flags set. `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files --user-data-dir="/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/temp-chrome"`

Comment: Hey, nah, not working. Chrome was definitely new as all my extensions were gone as well as passwords. Still getting the same error...

Comment: You are still trying to load an image file with a cross domain request? If you load file from local filesystem there should not be an error. For cross domain requests you can try using `YQL` to request resource

Comment: Yeah, but that is what I want to do, is use a URL instead of downloading to my own server. Essentially, I just want a thumbnail of a gif if the user enters a gif as the URL. I don't mind using a different strategy if you can think of something or a different NPM?

Comment: See [Directly download img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170063/directly-download-img-tag/44170392#44170392)

Comment: Okay, that last response is looking close but now I'm getting undefined back... my code looks like this: `let query = \`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from data.uri where url="${gifURL}"&format=json&callback=\`; fetch(query).then(response => response.json()).then(({query: {results: {gifURL}}}) => { console.log(gifURL)}).catch(err => console.log(err));` My request URL look like this: `https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url=%22https://media1.giphy.com/avatars/nikdudukovic/ylDRTR05sy6M.gif%22&format=json&callback=`

Comment: `({query: {results: {gifURL}}})` should be `({query: {results: {url}}})` we are using object destructuring to get the `url` property of `query.results` object of response. Alternatively, `.then(function(data){console.log(data.query.results.url)})`. Though did not so at link, `const url` should probably be a different identifier to avoid confusion

Comment: Hmm, I am getting `undefined`... I now have: `fetch(query).then(response => response.json()).then(({query: {results:{url}}}) => {
          console.log(url);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: When I check in the browser, I am getting a query response but no URL: `{
  "query": {
    "count": 1,
    "created": "2017-06-05T02:17:50Z",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "results": {
      "error": "337783 > 25600"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Try another image resource location

Comment: Not sure if the generated `data URI` of `.gif` `Content-Length` is too large for browser to handle

Comment: yeah, I'm consistently getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of null`

Comment: I like where you are going with this, as I was thinking of using an api to make the change...