# Set file name and format if file or file location contains neither

Tags: javascript, html, file, download

I'd like to set the file name and format of a "non-typical file", for a lack of better words. The files are stored at locations such as the following...

`let link = https://.../videoplayback?ipbits=0&initcwndb...D134213BA9465CB74DFD36CDE47BF.102638C4A9F3ACA357F79EE747DD5F49F1E0F0DE`

When one downloads such files, even if they are completely different files, they always end up being saved with the same name and never a file extension.

I've tried `url.download = link + '.mp4'`, but this has no effect whatsoever.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you sourcing the files?

Comment: @TheChetan downloading them off of the internet via the browser

Comment: @Anthony Are the files served with `CORS` headers?

Comment: @guest271314 i have no idea. how would i even determine that? ajax or something?

Comment: @Anthony Do you have control over the files?

Comment: @guest271314 no i don't, but the files are available online. additionally, there's no way i'd be able to download the files and serve them either.

Comment: Yes you can download the files and serve them from your `document` if the files have CORS headers, or using a proxy. Are all of the files media files?

Comment: i won't be able to download and serve them myself :/ yes, they're all media files. vorbis, opus, and webm formats i believe

Answer (score 6):

According to the MDN for [anchor tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) with the **download** attribute:

> Can be used with blob: URLs and data: URLs, to make it easy for users
>   to download content that is generated programmatically using
>   JavaScript (e.g. a picture created using an online drawing Web app).
>
> If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: is present and gives a
>   different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority
>   over this attribute.
>
> If this attribute is present and Content-Disposition: is set to
>   inline, Firefox gives priority to Content-Disposition, like for the
>   filename case, while Chrome gives priority to the download attribute.
>
> **This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the**
>   **same-origin.**

So if you are dynamically generating these links and they come from your own server - you can set the filename. *A cross-origin request will not work!*

You may be able use ajax to fetch the file as a blob and trick the browser into thinking that the data is not cross-origin. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909763/download-attribute-with-a-file-name-not-working) for one possible implementation.

Comment: In attempting this on localhost / jsfiddle - download attr alone doesn't work. I'm thinking its something to do with localhost not acting as a server. Might work on apache, but I didn't want to do that in case you done have it set up locally. This workaround fixed it though: https://gist.github.com/nelsonkhan/7d4e4b5c2f6898cf6a40bc12a236cbbb

Comment: The above will most likely work on newer browsers but IE support is a known issue. i'm not sure on mobile browsers - I can't find compatibility info anywhere...

Comment: i just need this to work on Chrome. and it will always be cross-origin. i'm not sure how that post you linked describes how to trick the browser into assuming the cross-origin is same-origin??

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to perform a `HEAD` request before setting `.download` property of `<a>` element to determine the `Content-Type` of the requested resource, use a `JSON` string, JavaScript object or other key, value pair data storage format to reflect pairs of valid `MIME` types to valid file extensions corresponding to the `MIME` type property. Use `.indexOf()`, `RegExp` or other filtering method to determine if there is a match between the property name of the string or object and the value of the property, if true store the extension value and concatenate the extension to the suggested file name.

If the file is not served with CORS headers you can try using a proxy to make `HEAD` of `GET` request to get the `Content-Type` header before setting the `.download` attribute.

It should be noted that the `.download` attribute is only a suggestion to the user for the filename. The user can change the name of the file at any time, including deleting the file extension, for whatever reason they may or may not have. Or not download the resource at all.

```js
const mimeTypeExtensions = {
  "text/plain": ".txt",
  "video/mp4": ".mp4",
  /* valid MIME types and corresponding extensions */
}

const a = document.querySelector("a");

a.addEventListener("click", event => {

  if (!a.download) {
  
    event.preventDefault();
    
    fetch(a.href, {method: "HEAD"})
    .then(response => {
      const mimeType = response.headers.get("content-type");
      let fileExtension = "";
      for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(mimeTypeExtensions)) {
          if (key.indexOf(mimeType) > -1) {
            fileExtension = prop;
            break;
          };
       }
       a.download = `filename${fileExtension}`;
       a.click();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))

  }

});
```

```html
<a href="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/11edc4566ba94f204dd46e6ae26edaad/raw/d118e99abbe2a2c60634e46816df9e1b9de6b6b8/D134213BA9465CB74DFD36CDE47BF102638C4A9F3ACA357F79EE747DD5F49F1E0F0DE">click</a>
```

Comment: i'm going to have to reread this when i get some time. can you elaborate about "...using a proxy to make `HEAD` of `GET` request...". i think i get the gist of what you're saying but the wording is hard to understand

Comment: @Anthony You can use `YQL` to request the file, then parse the `Content-Type` of the response, or use the response itself to set at `<a>` element `.href` see [Directly download img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44170063/), where `MIME` type portion of `data URI` can be parsed to perform same procedure at Answer to set file extension suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy option if you don't mind adding a library. [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) handles these cases well while hiding the ugly details.  I was going to go into how you could create Blob, write the contents of the download into it, and then create an anchor tag with an Object URL created from the Blob, but FileSaver handles that already and you could look at the source if you really wanted.

Just modify the following to add some checks and logic for determining filename/filetype and you should be able to tackle your use case.

```
<script src="cdn-to-FileSaver.js"></script>

<script>
var url = ...;
fetch(url).then((response) => {
  var blob = response.blob();
  var filename = 'song.mp4';

  saveAs(blob, filename);
});
</script>
```

Comment: i'll def check that out when i get some free time