# How can I download image which is rendered with <img> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, image, download

Let me explain my use case:

I have a page, where I fetch the image by the url (from remote host) and display it. Also, I have  a button on the page. When clicked, the image should be downloaded. I want to download the image without making any other remote calls.

So overall I want to support two things with a single fetch of the image:

- Customer should be able to see the rendered image on the page.
- Customer should be able to download the image by clicking the button.

Can you help me with how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Directly download img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170063/directly-download-img-tag)

Comment: Not fully actually. I see that it will start to download the image instantly. But what about displaying the image?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an answer to this:

You said that you would fetch the image:

Code should look something like this, so it is easy to extend.

```
let imageData
fetch('http://example.com/picture.png')
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(data => {
  const urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  imageData = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.data);
  document.querySelector("#your-image").src = imageData ;
//add this
  document.querySelector("#your-link").href = imageData 
  //here, make sure your link has a download tag in the HTML or in the javascript
//
});
```

Demo: https://streamable.com/ize3yh

Answer (score 0):

Did you see window.location.href ? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

in my reference project I was taking an image from the back end, making a URL.createObjectURL (img) and assigning a function to a button that simply does window.href.location = Processedimage on on: click. This way you can open the original image in another browser window, but again, I don't know how useful it will be. it is however a possible solution

Comment: I don't see how it helps here. My point is to fetch the image from the remote host only once and support displaying and download as well.

Comment: in my reference project I was taking an image from the back end, making a URL.createObjectURL (img) and assigning a function to a button that simply does window.href.location = Processedimage on on: click. This way you can open the original image in another browser window, but again, I don't know how useful it will be. it is however a possible solution

Comment: No, I don't want to go to another page. I want to display the image on the page, and when clicked the button, start downloading the image from the browser.